# autonindex on and need to remove the path on webpage

Tags: html, nginx

I have installed a website on Nginx..this is running on Linux. I have set autoindex on and the folder listing is happening. I need to remove the "index of /path" whenever the folder is traversed on the webpage. Any suggestions are highly appreciated, thanks

***Screenshot of the path:***

[image]

Comment: That is the default NGINX file transversal layout. To change it, you need to add your own `index`, most commonly `index.html`. Note that you need to do this for each folder that you want to mask.

Comment: See the [Custom autoindex pages with nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/312796/custom-autoindex-pages-with-nginx) ServerFault thread. Another way is to use something like [`ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html), but since that native module doesn't support regex expressions, you'll need a third-party module, e.g. [`ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module`](https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module).

Comment: Thanks..it works..cheers !!